# Ordered Probit in Jags Using scaled inverse wishart

Tags: jags

I am trying to use the following code (adapted from the code given in Gelman and Hill's Book) to estimate a varying coefficient/intercept ordered probit model in Jags. However, it is giving me a **"Observed node inconsistent with unobserved parents at initialization.Try setting appropriate initial values"**. Where am I going wrong? Could somebody please help me? Thanks in advance !!

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE));
options(warn=-1)
library(mvtnorm)
library(arm)
library(foreign)
library("R2jags")
library(MCMCpack)

set.seed(1)

standardizeCols = function( dataMat ) {
    zDataMat = dataMat
    for ( colIdx in 1:NCOL( dataMat ) ) {
        mCol = mean( dataMat[,colIdx] )
        sdCol = sd( dataMat[,colIdx] )
        zDataMat[,colIdx] = ( dataMat[,colIdx] - mCol ) / sdCol
    }
    return( zDataMat )
}

keep<-1
nobs = 150;
nis<-sample(1:40,nobs,replace=T)    # number obs per subject 
id<-rep(1:nobs,nis)
N<-length(id)
corr_beta = 0.6;
Sigma_beta = matrix(c(1, corr_beta, corr_beta, corr_beta, 
              corr_beta, 1, corr_beta, corr_beta,
              corr_beta, corr_beta, 1, corr_beta,
              corr_beta, corr_beta, corr_beta, 1), ncol=4);
betas <- rmvnorm(n=N, mean=c(-1.45, 0.90, 0.25, -2.3), sigma=Sigma_beta);

#Generate the data
x3 = matrix(0, nrow=N,ncol=3);
y3 = matrix(0, nrow=N,ncol=1);

for (i in 1:N) {
    error_v = rnorm(1,0,1);
    x3[i,1] = rnorm(1,0,1);
    x3[i,2] = rnorm(1,0,1);
    x3[i,3] = rnorm(1,0,1);
    y3[i,1] = betas[id[i], 1] + betas[id[i], 2]*x3[i,1] + betas[id[i], 3]*x3[i,2] + betas[id[i], 4]*x3[i,3] + error_v;
}
cutoff=c(-100, 0, 1.5, 2.4,   100)
k=length(cutoff)-1;
Y3<-cut(y3, br = cutoff, right=TRUE, include.lowest = TRUE, labels = FALSE)
Y3=Y3
X3=x3
m1=max(Y3)

y = as.vector( Y3 )
n = length(y)
J<-length(unique(id))
X =  cbind(1, standardizeCols( X3 ))
nPred = NCOL(X) 
subjects<-as.vector(as.numeric(id))
K=nPred
W <- diag (K)

# MCMC settings
ni <- 5000; nb <- 2500; nt <- 6; nc <- 3 

tau1u=c(0,1,2)
jags_data <- list ("n", "J", "K", "y", "subjects", "X", "W", "m1")

inits <- function (){
    list (B.raw=array(rnorm(J*K),c(J,K)), mu.raw=rnorm(K), sigma.y=runif(1), Tau.B.raw=rwish(K+1,diag(K)), xi=runif(K))
}

params <- c ("B", "mu", "sigma.B", "rho.B", "tau1u")

cat("model {

    for (i in 1:n){
        y.hat[i] <- inprod(B[subjects[i],],X[i,])
        y[i] ~ dcat(p[i,])
        estar[i]~dnorm (y.hat[i], tau.y);


        for (j in 1:(m1-1)) {
            Q1[i,j]<-pnorm(tau1[j]-estar[i],0,1)
        }

        p[i,1] <- Q1[i,1]
        for(j in 2:(m1-1)) {
            p[i,j] <- Q1[i,j] - Q1[i,j-1]
        }
        p[i,m1] <- 1 - Q1[i,m1-1] 
    }

    tau.y <- pow(sigma.y, -2)
    sigma.y ~ dunif (0, 100)

    # thresholds (unordered priors)
    for(j in 1:(m1-1)){
      tau1u[j] ~ dnorm(0,.01)
    }

    # ordered thresholds
    tau1 <- sort(tau1u)

    for (j in 1:J){
        for (k in 1:K){
            B[j,k] <- xi[k]*B.raw[j,k]
        }
        B.raw[j,1:K] ~ dmnorm (mu.raw[], Tau.B.raw[,])
    }
    for (k in 1:K){
        mu[k] <- xi[k]*mu.raw[k]
        mu.raw[k] ~ dnorm (0, .0001)
        xi[k] ~ dunif (0, 100)
    }

    Tau.B.raw[1:K,1:K] ~ dwish (W[,], df)
    df <- K+1
    Sigma.B.raw[1:K,1:K] <- inverse(Tau.B.raw[,])

    for (k in 1:K){
        for (k.prime in 1:K){
            rho.B[k,k.prime] <- Sigma.B.raw[k,k.prime]/sqrt(Sigma.B.raw[k,k]*Sigma.B.raw[k.prime,k.prime])
        }
        sigma.B[k] <- abs(xi[k])*sqrt(Sigma.B.raw[k,k])
    }
}", fill=TRUE, file="wishart2.txt")

# Start Gibbs sampler
outj <- jags(jags_data, inits=inits, parameters.to.save=params, model.file="wishart2.txt", n.thin=nt, n.chains=nc, n.burnin=nb, n.iter=ni)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial values function returns random numbers from normal and uniform distributions, which it appears are not close enough to sensible values to allow a non-0 posterior value to be calculated. I think you need to choose your initial values more carefully, and perhaps based on the values generated in the data, to ensure that the model compiles. Do Gelman and Hill give initial values for their model that you could start with?

Update: you could also try removing your 'inits=inits' argument to allow JAGS to select its own initial values, which works for most (although not all) models. I dont use R2JAGS though so I'm not sure if this is allowed for the jags function (but it is for rjags and runjags).

Comment: Hi Matt, Thank you so much for your response!! I tried to run it without init but it didn't work. I am actually trying to adapt Gelman and Hill's code for varying-intercepts, varying-slopes regression to an Ordered Probit. In the regression scenario the init values given in the book are similar and they work well.

Comment: Are you using the same data as Gelman and Hill? If your data is different, their initial values might not be sensible for your data even with the same model. One strategy you could try is fitting a reduced model (by fixing some effects or variance parameters to 0) and see if that will compile - then use good values from the posterior of the simple model to compile the more complex model.

Comment: Hi Matt,

Thank you again for helping me!! I was not exactly using the same data as Gelman and Hill. The following code is apparently running. But the recovered parameters are not very precise (especially the intercept term). I am not too sure why..I shall try a longer run and see if things improve
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37114187/JagsOProbit.txt